# jQuery jsonp request for text response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am sending a `jsonp` request to an URL to fetch the result as below. I am using jquery version 2.1.3

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'https://testdemo.com?q=moto',
   dataType:"jsonp",
   crossDomain: true,
   success: function(result) {
      alert("success");
   },
   error: function(obj, errorStr) {
      alert("error" + errorStr);
   }
});
```

It executes successfully, but it throws `parseerror`. The reason might be that the response is not in require `jsonp` format. 
Below is the response.

```
completion = ["moto",["moto 360","motorcycle","moto g 3rd generation","motorola","moto 360 2nd gen","motorcycle helmet","moto 360 2","motorcycle accessories","motorcycle gloves","moto g"],[{"nodes":[{"name":"Electronics","alias":"electronics"},{"name":"Cell Phones & Accessories","alias":"mobile"},{"name":"Warehouse Deals","alias":"warehouse-deals"},{"name":"Men's Watches","alias":"fashion-mens-watches"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[]];String();
```

I don't have controller over source/server code so I can not change the response format.

In that case, how I can get response as string.

I have also tried the suggested solutions like setting `dataType` as `jsonp text` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The correct answer is that you can't! If the response isn't in JSONP format, and the server doesn't support CORS, you can't get the data clientside, you'll have to use a serverside script to get it.

Comment: @adeneo thanks for answer but I need data clientside. I got the response in network but not getting response of success.